# Mkdir in php set wrong permission

Tags: php, mkdir, php-5.4, php-5.5

I have the following code :

```
if  (!file_exists('/public_html/'.'classic/'.'test'.'/'))  {
    if(!mkdir('/public_html/'.'classic/'.'test'.'/',  0777,  true))  {
        return  false;
    }
}
```

This create only the folder `/classic` witch have the permission 0755 and another `owner`. How to change to create recusively 2 folders : `/classic/test/` ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Give permission to main directory then all subdirectory inside it is automatically get updated with new permission.

Comment: Why are you using dots between the  different folder names? Mode doesn't seem to work on Windows. Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using umask :

```
$oldumask = umask(0);
mkdir('mydir', 0777); // or even 01777 so you get the sticky bit set
umask($oldumask);
```